# Tag a message on the filebeat side to be able to filter on kibana ( HTTP response codes )

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filter, filebeat

I have this configuration:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/secure
    - /var/log/audit/audit.log
    - /var/log/yum.log
    - /root/.bash_history
    - /var/log/neutron/*.log
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
    - /var/log/keystone/keystone.log
    - /var/log/httpd/error_log
    - /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
    - /var/log/glance/*.log
    - /var/log/rabbitmq/*.log
  ignore_older: 72h
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["sdsds"]
```

I would like to tag a log if it contains the following patter:
message:*INFO*HTTP*200*
I want to create a query on kibana to filter based on http response codes tag. How can I create this? Can you help me to create the condition with tags?
This response codes are in the nova-api and neutron server logs.
And I don't want to actually filter out the logs, I want to have everything in elastic search, just want to add tag to these kind of logs.

UPDATE:

I managed to figure out something, but I'm not sure what is the best way to list it, because I have many response codes:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/secure
    - /var/log/audit/audit.log
    - /var/log/yum.log
    - /root/.bash_history
    - /var/log/neutron/*.log
    - /var/log/keystone/keystone.log
    - /var/log/httpd/error_log
    - /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
    - /var/log/glance/*.log
    - /var/log/rabbitmq/*.log
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  include_lines: ["status: 200"]
  fields_under_root: true
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 200
  ignore_older: 72h
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
```

I have to create multiple times these 4 lines?

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/secure
    - /var/log/audit/audit.log
    - /var/log/yum.log
    - /root/.bash_history
    - /var/log/keystone/keystone.log
    - /var/log/neutron/*.log
    - /var/log/httpd/error_log
    - /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
    - /var/log/glance/*.log
    - /var/log/rabbitmq/*.log
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 200"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 200
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 202"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 202
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 204"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 204
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 207"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 207
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 403"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 403
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 404"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 404
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["status: 500"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 500
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nova/*.log
  fields_under_root: true
  include_lines: ["HTTP 503"]
  fields:
    httpresponsecode: 503
  ignore_older: 72h
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
  hosts: [
```

What is the best way to do this to multiple files and multiple codes?

UPDATE2:
My solution doesn't work, at the beginning it is sending and after completely stops.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: I see you're streaming your logs through Logstash, why not adding that tag in a Logstash filter?

Comment: Because the other team doesn't want to apply filter on the indexer if it affects only a small amount of servers :D

Comment: Please have a look on the processors in filebeat (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-reference-yml.html) which enables you to "Filter and enhance the exported data" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.5/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html). Maybe this is what you're looking for (if you are able to define a proper condition).

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question, but in that case, I would go the grok route.

If you know that your status field always looks like this, then why not do a pattern like this:

```
match => { 
  "message" => "<prepending patterns> status: %{NUMBER:httpresponsecode} <patterns that follow>" 
}
```

This would create a field called `httpresponsecode` which is filled with the number that follows the string `"status: "`

However, based on the [ECS](https://github.com/elastic/ecs)-Formats, I'd rather call the field something else, like
http.response.status(.keyword)

As for your specified logline, a valid grok pattern might look like this:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NONNEGINT:message.number} %{WORD:loglevel} %{DATA:application} \[-\] %{IP:source.ip} "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:http.request.path}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:http.version})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" status: %{NONNEGINT:http.response.status} len: %{NUMBER:http.response.length} time: %{NUMBER:http.response.time}
```

Find the Grok-Patterns for logstash in the [logstash repository](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns)
Use the Grok-Debugger [included in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/grokdebugger-getting-started.html) to see how your pattern would match.

Rename the fields accordingly.

Comment: Hi, this will be okay for solution but can you help me to create this for these lines: 2018-11-22 03:49:12.508 116770 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server [-] 10.118.220.228 "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" status: 200 len: 505 time: 0.0005932 I'm just interested in the status things but I have to provide this pattern for them.

Comment: If you use kibana, there should be a grok-debugger included, otherwise you might try [this one](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). Find the grok patterns [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) 

I've updated the answer, however, you should really look into writing grok filters on your own. For data ingestion and preparation this is your first stop.